# Dovecot handshake failure, on Postfix success

Tags: mysql, debian, ssl, postfix, dovecot

I am trying to setup a Dovecot/Postfix structure, relying on a MySQL backend. I came across a problem with SSL configuration, and it's really tearing my hair out...

### Situation

Dovecot listens on port 993 (IMAPs) and 995 (POP3s). I use the following command to test the connection :

```
openssl s_client -connect myserver.tld:993
openssl s_client -connect myserver.tld:995
```

The following error occurs :

```
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I've made the same tests forcing `ssl2`, `ssl3` and `tls1`, same thing. Now, when I run the same test on port 465 (SMTPs by Postfix) :

```
openssl s_client -connect myserver.tld:465
```

I get a magical `220 myserver.tld ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU).` Wonderful. MySQL-based authentication even works ! The problem is that Dovecot cannot initiate the SSL connection properly, when Postfix can. Both services share the same configuration, Postfix even uses Dovecot authentication.

### Configuration

**Dovecot configuration :**

```
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/myserver/myserver.tld.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/myserver/myserver.tld.key
ssl_verify_client_cert = no
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3 !TLSv1
ssl_cipher_list = HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!TLSv1.0:!aNULL:!MD5
```

**Postfix main configuration :**

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/myserver/myserver.tld.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/myserver/myserver.tld.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination
```

**Postfix master configuration :**

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
```

The SSL certificate is self-signed, I generated it myself. Over SMTP, it looks just fine.

### Logs

```
pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xx.xx.xx.xx, lip=xx.xx.xx.xx, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher, session=<ffu9UFnxZQBtvqmF>
```

(I get an "unknown protocol" when trying ssl2 or tls1 with the `openssl s_client` utility)

Anyone knows where I made the configuration mistake for Dovecot ?

Comment: You have denied all SSL protocols and ciphers within dovecot. Comment out lines `ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3 !TLSv1` and 
`ssl_cipher_list = HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!TLSv1.0:!aNULL:!MD5`

Comment: I actually removed '!'s. I still want a restriction, yet I read docs too quickly ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have actually disabled SSLv2, SSLv3, and TLSv1.0 in dovecot.

```
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3 !TLSv1
ssl_cipher_list = HIGH:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!TLSv1.0:!aNULL:!MD5
```

This is a problem because some clients don't yet speak TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2, your only remaining choices.

Try not disabling TLSv1.0 and see if you get any farther.

Comment: And this, is how I get ridiculous reading docs too quickly. Thanks a lot, `openssl s_client` is much nicer now. Yet for some unknown reason, Thunderbird still fails authenticating...